# Modifying the elements inside the array

Tags: bash, perl

I have an array that looks like this:

```
 C32
14(C55
2(C14
C10
3(C20
C10
2(O4 *149(H2
ZN C14
6(C5 6(C7 6(C3 6(C8 6(C11
```

I don't know if it is possible but I am trying to figure it out how to do it for days. So basically what I need is to modify the elements of this array so that for each element of the array (only if it contains C) I would like to delete two/three charachters before, whenever it ecounters C. So I will end up with something like this:

```
    C32
    C55
    C14
    C10
    C20
    C10
    2(O4 *149(H2
    C14
    C5 C7 C6 C8 C11
```

Comment: Just for my understanding: in your first block each line represents one array element and they make up a 9-element array, right?

Comment: Yeah thats right.. So I basically have many files and I wrote a script to read each file and whenever it meets specific line I splitted this by space. Then I push 4th element into an array but can only make use of it if it is organized as in the second block. So, for nine files nine element array.

Comment: Your output isn't consistent based on your input - you strip the single space from the first line, but keep the spaces on the last.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed`. Assuming your input file is *input.txt*:

```
sed '/C/s/[0-9]*(C/C/g' input.txt | sed '/C/s/^[^C]*//'
```

The first `sed` command removes the digits and parenthese before C, the second one, removes spaces and other chars before a C standing alone.

For the example, this is working. You will have to check that all the cases are matched.

Comment: It's also not a perl solution as requested

Comment: If you want a perl solution, I suggest you to remove the bash tag from the question. I thought it was bash **or** perl.

Comment: Yes, it was bash or perl, although perl is "preffered". For me either is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array = ('C32',
             '14(C55',
             '2(C14',
             'C10',
             '3(C20',
             'C10',
             '2(O4 *149(H2',
             'ZN C14',
             '6(C5 6(C7 6(C3 6(C8 6(C11');

my @expected = ('C32',
                'C55',
                'C14',
                'C10',
                'C20',
                'C10',
                '2(O4 *149(H2',
                'C14',
                'C5 C7 C6 C8 C11');

s/\S\S.?C/C/g for @array;

use Test::More tests => 1;
is_deeply \@array, \@expected;
```

Note that the test fails because `C3` and `C6` are not equal.

Comment: choroba: Thank You very much for this solution! All the best!

Comment: @sergio Please read [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But take your time; don't hurry.

Answer (score 0):

with bash:

```
mapfile -t arr <<END
 C32
14(C55
2(C14
C10
3(C20
C10
2(O4 *149(H2
ZN C14
6(C5 6(C7 6(C3 6(C8 6(C11
END

for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do 
    if [[ ${arr[i]} == *C* ]]; then
        # replace digits and open parentheses before a C
        arr[i]=${arr[i]//+([0-9])(C/C}
    fi
done

printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

```
 C32
C55
C14
C10
C20
C10
2(O4 *149(H2
ZN C14
C5 C7 C3 C8 C11
```